# Trying to append text with number

Tags: excel, vba

I have an ID Cell in my worksheet that is numerical, and used to control row ID. I use the following line of code:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 + 1
```

to increment the ID number each time a new line is inserted. It works well to increment that cell each time when my macro runs, but I would like to append the worksheet Tab Name on the front of the number. That is when my macro shows an (Runtime Error '13', Type mismatch) with the following line:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = TabName & ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 + 1
```

TabName is generated from the following Function:

```
    Function TabName() As String
     Application.Volatile
     TabName = ActiveSheet.Name
    End Function
```

Any suggestions how I can get this to work?

Regards,
S Dimm

Comment: You have no **=** at the beginning of the formula.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - I think that `.FormulaR1C1` is a hangover from a recorded macro and it is just a `.Value` that is actually being dealt with.

Comment: @Jeeped  but adding a **1** to *Text* is really tough!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - Only if you keep the worksheet name. If you remove it to do the math then add it again it's not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) you might want to continue down that road with the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
ActiveCell = _
  ActiveSheet.Name & Replace(ActiveCell.Value, ActiveSheet.Name, vbNullString) + 1
```

You have to remove the [Workbook.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195422.aspx) in order to add 1 to the increment then prefix the new number with the worksheet name again.